# Django settings.py S3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Django app runs in AWS.

Is there a way to restart a Django app and pick up new "config" without having to "push" the settings.py (or other) file?

My app uses settings.py and what I would like to do is find a way to change config without having to promote my code (and the settings.py file) through my dev, stage and prod environments.

I'm wondering if, for example, there is a way to tell Django (or in some other way) pick up the settings.py file from an S3 bucket on a restart?

It doesn't have to be the settings.py file, it's just what I'm thinking of since all the config is in there for now.

I'm aware that I could use AWS Secrets, but in my situation that would require updating 3 separate secrets (dev, stage, and prod) and so I was hoping for a "one place" solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you could create some environment variables that are loaded from the system. os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'). This way you avoid doing a push and you only have to change the variable in the machine.

Comment: Thanks Pablo.  I don't have direct access to the docker image in any of the AWS environments, so that wouldn't work for me, but it's a good idea!